# Calling a function of a class module

Tags: vba

When I try to call a function I created in a class module I get the error message

> object variable or with block is not declared

Minimal code example from both modules:

```vb
'calling
Dim AllZyklen1 As New ArrayList
For Each Wartungsplan In ArrayWartungsplan
       Set AllZyklen1 = Wartungsplan.GetAllZyklen 'added set
next Wartungsplan


'function itself
Public Function GetAllZyklen() As ArrayList

Dim AllZyklen2 As New ArrayList

'allZyklen2 gets calculated, no other functions are called just local varaibles of the class are used

If Not AllZyklen2.Contains(Zyklus) Then
            AllZyklen2.Add Zyklus
end if

Set GetAllZyklen = AllZyklen2 'added set

End Function
```

Numbers are added to `allzyklen` for easier reading, they are actually both called `allzyklen` without number.

Shouldn't that work? I can't see the error.

Comment: `ArrayList` is an Object Type, you need to use `Set` (both in your loop and in the function)

Comment: I changed it to "set AllZyklen1 = Wartungsplan.GetAllZyklen" and added the line "Set AllZyklen2 = New ArrayList". So far that didnt do the trick

Comment: can you please update your code in the question accordingly? The changes to make should sholud be `Set GetAllZyklen = AllZyklen2` and `Set AllZyklen1 = Wartungsplan.GetAllZyklen`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Set` for `Objects` (`ArrayList` is an object).

So it should be:

```
'calling
Dim AllZyklen1 As New ArrayList
For Each Wartungsplan In ArrayWartungsplan
    Set AllZyklen1 = Wartungsplan.GetAllZyklen
Next Wartungsplan
```

and

```
'function itself
Public Function GetAllZyklen() As ArrayList
    Dim AllZyklen2 As New ArrayList

    'allZyklen2 gets calculated, no other unctions are called just local varaibles of the class are used

    Set GetAllZyklen = AllZyklen2
End Function
```

---

Full example that works:

Class Module `ClassWartungsplan`:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetAllZyklen() As ArrayList
    Dim AllZyklen2 As New ArrayList

    'allZyklen2 gets calculated, no other unctions are called just local varaibles of the class are used
    AllZyklen2.Add "abc"

    Set GetAllZyklen = AllZyklen2
End Function
```

Standard Module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Example()
    Dim AllZyklen1 As New ArrayList
    
    Dim Wartungsplan As New ClassWartungsplan
    Set AllZyklen1 = Wartungsplan.GetAllZyklen
    
    Debug.Print AllZyklen1(0)  ' prints ABC in the immediate window
End Sub
```

Comment: hmm damn, I edited my code an tried it again like that but so far the same error appears. I also added a little of the calculate all zyklen part... just because its the only other place allzyklen gets used

Comment: Your code now says `AllZyklen.Contains` but you `Dim AllZyklen2`. Make sure you use `Option Explicit` so you don't mess up with variable naming. See my edit for a working example.

Comment: Damnit, i just double checked everything and its exactly like your example, still doesnt work, same error.

Comment: @G.M there must be something wrong because I tested the code and it worked. Open a new workbook add a class module name it `ClassWartungsplan` add the code and the other code in a normal module. Add the reference for the `ArrayList` in the VB editor. And it should run. • Make sure your variable names are different from the class name.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait. The Issue was what you posted and a simple spelling error of an attribute within the classmodule function. But not the line within the classmodule got highlighted but the call of this function, which made finding the error quiet difficult. I endet up creating a new function within the main class to make debugging easier. Thanks alot :)